# Get previous hour of UTC/GMT time using Perl

Tags: perl, date

I have a script which will print Start & End time of previous hour of UTC/GMT.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw(strftime);

my ($tmp_date, $tmp_hour, $Start, $End);

my $date = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', gmtime();
print "Date:$date\n";

my $hour = strftime '%H', gmtime();
print "Hour:$hour\n";

if ($hour == "00"){
    $tmp_date = $date-1;
    $tmp_hour  = "23";
} else {
    $tmp_hour  = $hour-1;
    $tmp_date = $date;
}
$a = length($tmp_hour);

if ($a == 1 ){
    $tmp_hour="0".$tmp_hour;
}

$Start = $tmp_date.".".$tmp_hour."00";
$End   = $tmp_date.".".$hour."05";

if ($End =~ /0005/){
    $tmp_date = `TZ=GMT-12 date +%Y%m%d`;
    $End  =$tmp_date.".".$hour."05";
}

print "Start:$Start, End:$End\n";
```

For example, lets say now UTC time is: Wed Jun 10 10:18:57 UTC 2020
This should print Start & End time as 2020-06-10.0900 2020-06-10.1005 respectively.

This script is working as expected. But when Daylight savings happens will there be any impact on fetching Start & End time?

I want experts suggestions how can I avoid unnecessary `if` statements and achieve it by the use of Perl module itself.

PS: Perl version: `v5.10.1`. Please suggest Perl modules which comes with standard Perl installation (Ex: `POSIX`, `Time::Local` etc.) for solution of above problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using `gmtime()`, any DST changes will have no effect at all.

I'm not sure why your end time ends with '05', I would have thought that the end of the hour comes at '00'.

Here's how I'd write it with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $end = gmtime->truncate(to => 'hour');
my $start = $end - ONE_HOUR;

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
say 'Start: ', $start->strftime($format);
say 'End: ', $end->strftime($format);
```

If you really want the end time to be five past the hour, then add this line after the `ONE_HOUR` line:

```
$end += (5 * ONE_MINUTE);
```

You can, of course, use any of the standard `strftime()` sequences to change the format of the output.